# SQL Server max and min date in row

Tags: sql-server, date, max, row

My SQL Server table has 200 dates in the same row:

```
ID  Date1  Data2  Date3  (..)  Date200
```

Is it possible to find the Min and Max date of one row?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like SELECT MAX(Date1) FROM Table  or SELECT MIN(Date1) FROM Table ?

Comment: Which RDMS are you using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is use a `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot the row.  **No need to list the 200 date columns** (Notice the `attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') Like 'Date%'` ).

You may also notice NULL will be omitted.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Date1 date,Date2 date,Date3 date)
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,'2016-01-01','2016-01-15','2016-02-01'),
(2,'2016-02-15',null,null)

Select A.ID
      ,C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select XMLData=cast((Select A.* For XML RAW) as xml)) B
 Cross Apply (
            Select MinDate = min(Value)
                  ,MaxDate = max(Value)
                 From  (
                        Select Value  = attr.value('.','date') 
                         From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as A(r)
                         Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
                         Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') Like 'Date%'
                       ) S
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  MinDate     MaxDate
1   2016-01-01  2016-02-01
2   2016-02-15  2016-02-15
```

**Edit - Another Option**

```
Select A.ID
      ,C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
            Select MinDate = min(Value)
                  ,MaxDate = max(Value)
                 From  (values (A.Date1)
                              ,(A.Date2)
                              ,(A.Date3)
                              -- .. More Columns
                       ) C1 (Value)
             ) C
```